# Selecting a button control in Excel 2013 without clicking it

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, activex

I want to change the name of a button control in Excel 2013. I have my properties window open ready to go. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to select the button without clicking it and invoking its action.

I tried going into design mode, but when I click on the button, nothing happens. It does not become selected.

Any help? The [Microsoft help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/select-or-deselect-controls-on-a-worksheet-HP010236695.aspx) is not particularly useful on this subject.

### EDIT

I forgot to mention, the format is an Excel 2003 .xls workbook, so it is being opened in compatibility mode. I don't know if this is part of the problem or not. I do not have the option of upgrading it as the end user has Office 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button on the sheet (in the cell):

Your button is in protected mode, you need right click it and go to "Formate" -> "Protection".
Remove both of the protections (text protection as well) and you will be able to edit the caption on click the button!

Button on User Form:

Over the "Properties" window as usually.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. However, in Excel 2013 it is under "Review" -> "Protect Workbook"

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are in design mode like you said you did then right click on the button. The grab windows should appear. Then left click on it and you can change the position and size.

Comment: Sorry, right clicking has no effect